# How to set up mailgun with laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel, email, mailgun

I am trying to set up mail sending with mailgun on my deployed laravel application. I am able to send email verification emails, but I can't send to my email. For example:

```
Notification::route('mail', 'admin@mywebsite.org')
        ->notify(new Feedback($user->email, $subject, $message));
```

When I was using mailtrap.io to test my mail sending it worked perfectly.

My .env file looks like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-<key>
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox<somenums>.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=<mypass>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

When I try to send the email it brings this error: Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings. "

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO.

Please have a deeper look at the Laravel [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#driver-prerequisites) where you can find everything you need to set up the mailgun driver.

> Mailgun Driver
>   To use the Mailgun driver, first install Guzzle, then set the driver option in your  config/mail.php configuration file to mailgun. Next, verify that your config/services.php configuration file contains the following options:
>
> ```
> 'mailgun' => [
>   'domain' => 'your-mailgun-domain',
>   'secret' => 'your-mailgun-key',
> ],
> ```

After updating your conf you have to change the `MAIL_DRIVER` env variable from `smtp` to `mailgun`. All the other settings for username, password and so on are not required.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I verified my mailgun account and now I can create real domains not sandbox. Now I have to set up DNS records for sending. For example: Hostname: mail.example.org, Type: TXT and Value: v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all and Hostname: smtp._domainkey.mail.example.org, Type TXT and Value: k=rsa; p=<LONG HASH>, but I am using fadedservers.com and when I try to add it it returns this error: "Domain name ID not found"

Comment: This question is not related to your Laravel question... You may have to ask in [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) community.

Anyway I don't think they'll give you an answer because it's a provider related problem... IMO the best solution for you is to open a ticket in fadedservers.com